# Nested JSON: property length of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to work with a nested array with a JSON in D3JS and can't figure out why in the world I'm getting a "property length undefined" error at the line which reads:

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.points); }).
```

Here's the JSON:

```
[
{
    "aspectRatio": 1.247386759581881,
    "closed": 1,
    "xyData": [
        {
            "x0": 0.53078594712060867,
            "x1": 0.95454545454545459,
            "x2": 0.95454545454545459,
            "x3": 0.53078594712060867,
            "x4": 0.53078594712060867,
            "y0": 0.52936622215603868,
            "y1": 0.52936622215603868,
            "y2": 0.13179275296659432,
            "y3": 0.13179275296659432,
            "y4": 0.52936622215603868
        }
    ]
},
{
    "aspectRatio": 1.247386759581881,
    "closed": 1,
    "xyData": [
        {
            "x0": 0.045454545454545435,
            "x1": 0.41126403477001078,
            "x2": 0.41126403477001078,
            "x3": 0.045454545454545435,
            "x4": 0.045454545454545435,
            "y0": 0.86820724703340568,
            "y1": 0.86820724703340568,
            "y2": 0.44804437618547044,
            "y3": 0.44804437618547044,
            "y4": 0.86820724703340568
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And here's the code:

```
function loadEss(filename,svgName,mainWidth){
var svgName;
d3.json(filename, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(kv){
        kv.xyData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.points = [];
            aspect=1.5;
            for (var i = 0; d["x"+i] !== "" && (typeof d["x"+i] !== 'undefined'); i++) {
                d.points.push([mainWidth*d["x"+i], mainWidth/aspect*(d["y"+i])]);
            }
            console.log(d.points);
        });
    });

    var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},    
        width = mainWidth - margin.left - margin.right,             
        height = mainWidth/aspect - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

    svgName= d3.select("body")                                  
        .append("svg")                                      
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)  
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")                                            
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 


    var line = 
    d3.svg.line() 
    .interpolate("linear-closed")
    ;

    svgName.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        ;

    svgName.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.points); })  
        .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin","round")
        ;
});

};
```

This work is based off of two previous topics: [Nested JSON array and D3JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033609/nested-json-array-and-d3js) and [d3JS: Drawing Line Segments from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769330/d3js-drawing-line-segments-from-csv)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWPrV/)

That array of points that you're building is getting stored in the wrong place, so further below `d.points` is null when you pass it to `line()`. Instead of `d.points` you need `kv.points`:

```
    kv.xyData.forEach(function(d) {
        kv.points = [];
        aspect=1.5;
        for (var i = 0; d["x"+i] !== "" && (typeof d["x"+i] !== 'undefined'); i++) {
            kv.points.push([mainWidth*d["x"+i], mainWidth/aspect*(d["y"+i])]);
        }
        console.log(kv.points);
    });
```